# Laravel (5) - how to use getKey() in a model manipulator on 'create'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, mutators

Im trying to create a news item and store its thumbnail at a location corresponding to its primary key: *$this->getKey*. This works on *update* since the key is available, but on *create* it is not.

I am using the manipulator *setThumbnailImageAttribute* to handle the file upload:

```
public function setThumbnailImageAttribute($value) {
    $this->setImage(
        'thumbnail_image',
        $value,
        'news/'.$this->getKey().'/thumbnail_image/'
    );
}
```

*setImage* handles the upload and setting the correct value to the attribute (and so the database)

On *update* this results **correctly** in:

> 'news/1/thumbnail_image/'

On *create* this results **incorrectly** in:

> 'news//thumbnail_image/'

How can I achieve this with a mutator, or is there a different approach?

Comment: This looks like a derived attribute. You should not store that in the database (especially considering that it's trivial to build it from an existing record).

Answer (score 1):

This is not achievable by your approach, yes! there are some nasty hacks to do so. But you've to manually call this method after the record has been created.

Comment: I was thinking in the same direction, but I Laravel calls this method with $value.. mm maybe I could get that manually out of request()

Answer (score 0):

in model file , you can use these methods, you can easliy inject your code inside saved method

```php
class SomeTable extends Model
{
 protected static function boot()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            print('creating  triggered');
            // print_r(var_dump($model));
            print_r(var_dump($model->getKey())); //returns null
        });
        static::saving(function ($model) {
            print('saving  triggered');
            print_r(var_dump($model->getKey())); // returns null
        });
        static::saved(function ($model) {
            print('saved session triggered');
            print_r(var_dump($model->getKey())); //returns the id
        });

        static::updating(function ($model) {
            print('updating  triggered');            
        });

        static::deleting(function ($model) {
            // bluh bluh
        });
        
        parent::boot();
    }

}
```